# Issues with SOCKS proxy over SSH Tunnel on windows - works via OS X

Tags: macos, ubuntu-10.04, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy

I setup an ssh tunnel to my ubuntu VPS from an OS X machine like this:

ssh -p 12345 -N -D 9999 root@128.222.222.222
password: *
etc.

I have tried to follow many a guide on how to use either putty or plink (preference) to achieve an ssh tunnel for socks proxy and not one of them has worked. It even connects and appears to be doing the same thing but I try browsing with my SOCKS proxy configured and nada.

Where do I go from here?

Here is the example I have used to try and connect putty with an SSH tunnel:

http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html

There are many like it and they all suggest that this should provide the same outcome as the ssh statement I used in OSX. I get connected but setting my SOCKS proxy to 127.0.0.1:9999 does not allow me to browse anything.

Comment: Right-click on putty title bar, select Event Log and check if you see incoming connectiong to socks proxy from browser. (`Opening connection to...`)

Comment: Interesting! I'm seeing:  Opening connection to 127.0.0.1:9999 for forwarding. Forwarded connection refused by server. Connect failed.  I wonder why this would be when it works fine with OSX?

Comment: For the record I have every port available open to my machine, GatewayPorts yes, AllowTCPForwarding yes AllowAgentForwarding yes are all on

Comment: How did you setup the tunnel in putty? For socks, choose Source port (9999) and click on Dynamic option. Don't fill anything in Destination. Then in the browser fill 127.0.0.1:9999 as socks proxy address.

Comment: When I do this it says Local port 9999 SOCKS dynamic forwarding but IE doesn't let me browse.   No errors in Event Log.

Comment: If you don't see connection attemps in putty's Event Log, then IE is not using 127.0.0.1:9999 as proxy server. You can try for example `netstat -n` to check if there is any active connection to the proxy server, or IE tries to connect directly.